# Where to add custom menu items to UIMenuController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uimenucontroller

I created a subclass of UITextView and now I want to extend the default `UIMenuController` by adding some buttons. Performing the extension is no problem at all, I just need to add some `UIMenuItem` so the `menuItems` array of the shared instance of the `UIMenuController`.

My question is now: Where do I perform this manipulation? The MenuController is a singleton implementation, so every change I make will affect all the other views that support the menu. So where am I going to add the extra menu items and where do I later remove them again? I am searching for some kind of equivalent to the UIViewController's `viewWillAppear` method.

Or am I worrying way too much and it is perfectly good practice to implement it in the view controller of the view containing my `UITextView` subclass? 
However, this means that every view controller containing my class as subview would have to implement the same code. Is there a better way?

Edit: Another option is of course to keep the selectors for my class unique and have all other custom views return `NO` for the selector in `-respondsToSelector:`. This seems to be the best solution so far to me.

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it works fine to add the items in the app delegate. You need to make sure of course, that other Views supporting the MenuController return `NO` for your particular selector in `-respondsToSelector:`.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Not sure about best practice.

You probably want to use the viewDidAppear and viewWillDisappear to modify that.